# How to get PublicKey of a csproj file for use in `InternalsVisibleTo`?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have a signed assembly where I'd like to use `InternalsVisibleTo`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("My.Project.Name", PublicKey=002400000...")]
```

Where I also have a `My.Project.Name.csproj` in another directory that has `My.Project.Name` as the `AssemblyName`.  I need to get the `PublicKey` for this assembly. How do I do that using the command line tools?

Various references indicate I call `sn -Tp path-to-assembly` but I don't have a path yet. I need the PublicKey first since I can't compile until the internals are visible to this assembly.

I also use a `<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>` in both projects, which I presume is for the signing, but I'm not clear on if, or how, this relates to the PublicKey I need.

*Note: I'm doing this on Mac using the Mono CLI toolkit.*

Comment: Just follow the steps in the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385180(v=vs.120).aspx).  Note how it does not require the assembly to extract the public key, the sn.exe -p step is crucial.